# Sequelizer console.log output not printing

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm learning how to use Sequelize to persist data to a MySql database from a NodeJS application. The following script is my attempt to insert data into a table which has some records in it.

The issue is I am attempting to debug the script in various locations using console.log but I get no output.

```
const db = require('../engage/db');
conn = db.conn

function init() {
    const Reductions = conn.sequelize.define('Reductions', {
        pid : {
            type: conn.Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        code : {
            type: conn.Sequelize.STRING
        },
        duration : {
            type: conn.Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER
        }
    });
    return Reductions
}

async function insert(p) {
    console.log('Testing @ insert() entrance : ', p)
    
    let table = await init(conn.sequelize, conn.Sequelize)
    
    // conn.sequelize.sync({force:true}).then( async () => {
    conn.sequelize.sync().then( async () => {
        conn.sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM Reductions WHERE pid = :pid',{
            replacements: {pid : p.id},
            type: conn.Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
        }).then((data) => {
            console.log('TESTING DATA: ', data)
            return data
        }).then((results) => {
            console.log('Checking results: ', results)
        })
    }).finally(() => {
        console.log('Reductions update complete')
    })
}

module.exports = { init, insert }
```

I an performing an SQL search and chaining **.then()** functions to debug the output.
But my problem is non of the console.log calls in the insert function are responding except for the first one.

I am very certain the required data is in the *Reductions* table of the database but even if it is not, the console.log in the finally section does not output either.

How can I understand and resolve why the console.logs are not printing?

### Update

Insert function call code, as requested.

```
.
.
.
properties.forEach(async(property) => {
    if( property.reduced !== false ) {
        await reductions.insert(property)
    } else {
        uninvestibles += 1
    }
})
.
.
.
```

Comment: can you try it after removing `async` after `conn.sequelize.sync().then(` ?

Comment: Thanks @RinkeshP.
I tried your suggestion but it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: can you show the part where you are calling the insert function?

Comment: @RinkeshP: I added the code section where the insert function is called as requested. Unfortunately the full script is large puppeeter project and the entire file would be overwhelming so I only added the small relevant section.

Comment: might I suggest you to use a normal for loop instead of for each? I have had problems with asynchronous code running inside foreach. Some googling shows foreach was not meant to be used with asynchronous code, it doesn't wait for the promise to resolve.

Comment: Thank you very much @RinkeshP. You were right and I might have never have found the issue originated from my use of a foreach loop. My application is responding correctly again after further simplifing my insert function code. If you would like to provide your input as an answer, I would be happy to accept it. Thanks again for your persistence.

Comment: if you could update your question with the simplified insert code, that would in writing a good answer

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to **Rinkesh P** for helping me find the answer to my problem.

Apparently the foreach loop does not wait for promises to resolve. So my await related code wouldn't execute as intended. Not so sure why and curiously my foreach solution had been working.

But apparently, foreach loops should not be used with asynchronous code. So I refactored my foreach into the following for loop:

```
for (let index = 0; index < properties.length; index++) {
    if( properties[index].reduced !== false ) {
        await reductions.insert(properties[index], location)
    } else {
        uninvestibles += 1
    }
}
```

That got my code working again.